# How to change keyboard brightness in windows 10 running Bootcamp through the power shell or command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, bootcamp

There is a file called [kbrightness](https://github.com/pirate/mac-keyboard-brightness/blob/master/kbrightness) for MacOS in which the command ./kbrightness x (where x is a number from 0.0 to 1) and it changes the Keyboard Brightness of my MacBook Pro to the specified amount (x).

So, I want to ask this -- is there a command/similar executable file for the Bootcamp, so that I can similarly change the keyboard brightness in the Bootcamp as well?

Comment: Boot camp is software that helps install windows. Are you looking for a windows software recommendation here?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the keyboard brightness through the Command Line in Windows.